# 8259A End of Interrupt (EOI) signal question

Tags: interrupts, x86

In the x86 architecture, when a hardware interrupt's ISR finishes you need to tell the 8259A chip that it is done and you send an EOI signal to the chip. After that you can return from the ISR using an IRET instruction.

question:
Is there any reason why the IRET instruction isn't hardwired to automatically send an EOI signal to the 8259A? Wouldn't that save some processing?

Comment: Its two instructions. IRET is a branch(jump) to another address, EOI is effectively a clear on the ISR register in the 8259A. I can imagine many scenario when you want to return a specific interupt routine and not clear the ISR on the interrupt handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two physical instructions here. IRET is a branch/jump and advances the program counter, pops some items off the stack, etc to return to the previous task that was interrupted. You use IRET in more scenarios that handling interrupts, including CPU exceptions and external interrupts that don't neccessarily go through the interrupt handler peripheral.

[IRET reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_145.html)

> Returns program control from an exception or interrupt handler to a program or procedure that was interrupted by an exception, an external interrupt, or a software-generated interrupt. **These instructions are also used to perform a return from a nested task**. (A nested task is created when a CALL instruction is used to initiate a task switch or when an interrupt or exception causes a task switch to an interrupt or exception handler.) See the section titled "Task Linking" in Chapter 6 of the IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 3.

EOI is a command given to the PIC (interupt controller) to clear the current interrupt and allow the PIC (8259A) to issue more interrupts. There is no requirement that there is only one PIC or that all system interrupts/exceptions/etc come from that one PIC so you must explicitly signal to the peripheral (whether a seperate IC like in original 8086 or integrated in one south bridge or on-die peripheral in modern x86)  to change state.

It may be easier conceptually to think of the 8259A as a seperate specialized microcontroller that happens to be ubiquitously attached to your CPU

Comment: Ah ok, because you don't know how many PICs there are, an IRET wouldn't be able to clear the right interrupt signal.

Comment: Yes, the instruction set has no operations for the PIC explicitly. Its an external device. A digital mitochondria